# Remaining with Integral relaxed integer linear programming

Tags: binary, linear-programming, integer-programming

When i relax my binary integer program (0,1) to LP (0< =x <=1), the solution seizes to be optimal since some of the x values are fractional. Is there a way i can relax  and still get an optimal solution. Thanks

Comment: If that would be possible, why do people bother to develop MIP solvers?

Answer (score 0):

No, in general that doesn't work. A tipical case when you can relax and still get an optimal solution is for totally unimodular matrices, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Total_unimodularity) for an introduction to the topic. Moreover, the integrality gap will depend on the particular formulation you use as a model. In general, when you have relaxed the integer program and get a fractional solution, you could use cutting planes and a branch-and-cut schema in order to get feasible integer solutions that have a relatively small integrality gap.